# What is the suffix for level 5 and above of elemental spells in Final Fantasy?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

Example Fire, Fira, Firaga, Firaja, ???
Has any source ever mention higher tier than -ja spells?

Comment: The -za level spells are next. Firaza, Blizzaza, and Thundaza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has any source ever mention higher tier than -ja spells

sorta. while [Frank's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327402/what-is-the-suffix-for-level-5-and-above-of-elemental-spells-in-final-fantasy#comment466706_327402) sounds correct (not sure where i heard it but seems correct to me too) there is (as of 27/02/2018) actually no [Thundaza](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Thundaza), [Firaza](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Firaza), [Blizzaza](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Blizzaza) or [Waterza](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Waterza) as all these pages on the wiki don't have pages to them, but if you replace the z with a j in their URLs you'll get the -ja level spells.

this is also backed up on the wikia's template for [Black Magic Template](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Template:Black_Magic) where under reoccurring we only see up to the -ja level and infact -ja is the highest level (so it's not a matter of Frank just getting the suffix wrong, there's no magic after -ja)

But ofcause this is just for named spells following this pattern, if we consider -ja level spells as being Level 4 (Normal, -ra, -ga, -ja) then we do have Level 5 spells

- in *Crisis Core: Final Fantasy VII* Elemental Magic Materia is actually split between levels (unlike what it was in *Final Fantasy VII* where the Lighting Materia would grant Bolt 1-3).

  in Crisis Core you have the inital 3, Normal, -ra and -ga but after this the next most powerful Magic Material after -ga is Dark [Normal] (ie. Dark Thunder). these, just like their regular one, are split between Normal, -ra and -ga so Level 5 Magic where would be Dark -ra spells.

  it would also be noted that after Dark there is Hell -ga spells where they skip Normal and -ra so you go from Dark Thundaga to Hell Thundaga

  Source: [Magic Materia (Crisis Core)](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Materia_(Crisis_Core))

---

Also in *Kingdom Hearts* it was slightly inconsistent. while they did feature -za this was infact the 4th level and was sometimes also -gun but in later installements to the series -ja was used for the 4th level

> The Kingdom Hearts series utilizes the tier system used from the Final Fantasy series to denote its levels of power with the same suffixes -ra and -ga for its spells. The exception is the fourth level, which tends to vary across the series, typically using -gun or -za, but later using -ja in later installments.

Source: [Magic tier system > Non-Final Fantasy guest appearance > Kingdom Hearts series](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_tier_system#Kingdom_Hearts_series)

Comment: I was using the Kingdom Hearts as reference, yes.